# Restoring backup with Deja Dup from external HD

Tags: external-hdd, deja-dup, restore

So, here's the problem that I have with restoring. First, I backed up like everything. So I had place on the external HD for only one copy.

I had to reinstall everything, but I didn't worry because I had a backup. But now, restoring doesn't work and it starts to be annoying.

So, I right click "Restore missing files...". Then I have the popup window from Deja Dup asking where is the backup. So, I select the external HD and either put nothing in "folder" or just put ".". Thinking that it should be the base to look for backups.

In both cases, after a while scanning, I get: The Volume "Filesystem root" has only 139.7mb disk space remaining. But my partition "/home" has 799.6Gb free. Also, I just want to restore some files, I don't need all of them.

On my external HD, there's a file called: duplicity-full.20120514T220834Z.manifest. A text file. In it, I can see that everything is partitions in files of 52mb. So, small files are in one archive while very large files are split in multiple one. But I can see the exact list of file that I have.

So, I'm guessing that my backup is intact.

What am I doing wrong ?

Is possible that it failes, even to list all the files, because I don't have enough space left on my ExtHD ? Why can't duplicity used another location to do that ?

Answer (score 4):

I advise you to try to restore a important files.

The commande line : `duplicity list-current-files --no-encryption file:///media/[rest of the root to your hard_disk] >  /home/yourusername/list.txt` don't liste all files in the backup since the beginning, [source](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.sysutils.backup.duplicity.general/4856)

and from author [You can restore the full monty or selected folders/files from a specific time.](http://www.nongnu.org/duplicity/duplicity.1.html)

Try to creat list of files and directory you need to restore using ***liste.txt*** generated by last commande and the liste of files in the manifest genereted by Deja Dup in backup directory like ***duplicity-full.20120922T175100Z.manifest***, (name it for example ***final_list.txt***)

**final_list.txt :**

```
home/username/music
home/username/file.mp3
...
```

**Creat restore directory**

```
$mkdir /tmp/restore
```

**Creat bash file Restore.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=$1
# Read file form list 
while read line 
do
    duplicity --no-encryption --file-to-restore  "$line"  file:///media/[rest of the root to your hard_disk] /tmp/restore/"$line" 
done <"$FILE"
```

**Restore you list**

```
$sh Restore.sh final_list.txt
```

Done! and good luck :)

Comment: I will try this! Thanks for the script too... if it works, will be quite handy :)

Answer (score 1):

I usually use duplicity to get part of the backups done with deja-dup (deja-dup is a front-end for duplicity)

The first thing I would do would be creating a list of files in your backup by, for instance:

```
duplicity list-current-files --no-encryption file:///media/[rest of the root to your hard_disk] >  /home/yourusername/list.txt  (if there is encryption, use the proper option)
```

If that works, your backup is OK. Then, with duplicity restore you should be able to restore everything, or with `duplicity --no-encryption --file-to-restore` just a folder or files (type 'man duplicity' in a terminal for more info, or ask if you have more doubts)

I hope your backup is safe!

Comment: I will try this and let you know... I have to reinstall... again my computer and I will try it.

Comment: That command... is it suppose to take forever?

Comment: After taking forever... I still have the same message that I don't have enough disk space! My external HD is full and because of that, it won't let me list the files! Same problem when trying to restore...